# Postgres 13: cannot psql from CMD (incorrect password but its correct?)

Tags: postgresql

[Image of my info and the error itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O21Oc.png)

Yes I can access it by Shell and pgAdmin but I cannot with direct psql command...
Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: I tried reinstalling it and watched 30 mins configuring pg_hba.conf and tried but no success

Comment: Do not use images for textual information. Copy and paste the information as text and add to your question.

Comment: Isn't CMD and Shell the same thing?  What does it mean that you can access it by Shell?

Comment: @jjanes sorry about that SQL shell is the built in postgres thing which i can access with my correct password but i cannot do anything directly from CMD

Comment: @AdrianKlaver is it a convention?

Comment: Yes, [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and from there [Images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: You probably need to use `-U` to specify the user you want to log in.  It is likely to be 'postgres' if you have set up anything else for it to be.  I don't know what the built-in-thing is or what it is doing, I don't have one of those, maybe it is an optional component I didn't install.

Comment: @jjanes - Is there a user named postgres and a database named postgres?

Comment: Yes, when I install from EDB installer, it automatically sets up a database with that user and that database already created.

Comment: Last question : Are there separate passwords for databases, for a owner/user and master password? -@jjanes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that confused me was from the CMD I managed to connect as AN USER NAMED "POSTGRES" and connected to  a database named "POSTGRES", for a while, I thought users and databases were one thing. Later, I thought that "POSTGRES" is like a master user and I can create many many databases with it then I found out I could create users ...

```
postgres=#CREATE USER me WITH PASSWORD '0000';
```

Add to that confusion, I managed to connect as an different user but it was still saying "postgres=#_" not a "differentuser=#" then I figured out that "postgres=#" is the database named "POSTGRES". There weren't any noob friendly tutorials on Youtube that I was able to find... I guess the pgAdmin 4 helped because I wasn't familiar yet with \du+ \l commands. I hope someone finds this useful.